# Prove that there are no $(x_1, \ldots, x_{14})$ that satisfy this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there is no $(x_1, \ldots, x_{14})$ that satisfy
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{14}x_{i}^{4} = 1599.$$

I think that there is a way to do this with modular arithmetic. A hint that is provided to me is it to consider $x^{2} \pmod{16}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 15$. So I made a table of all the values (I think I got only $0, 1, 4, 9$ as values), and also noted that $1599 \equiv 15 \pmod{16}$. But I cannot get anywhere with that.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What possibilities are there for $x^{\color{red}{4}} \pmod{16}$ ?

Comment: $0$ or $1$. Oh I think I get it

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  I did not notice the comments, sorry. Should I delete my answer ?

Comment: @Peter: No. Independent answers are always ok, in my opinion. Besides, you get more points for an answer:)

Comment: @Peter Marty is right. Your answer is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every integer $x$, we either have $$x^4\equiv 0\mod 16$$ or $$x^4\equiv 1\mod 16$$ This can be verified by inspection (the values for $0\le x\le 15$ are sufficient). With your observation, you can easily derive a contradiction.